# Symfony2, Doctrine2 : Multiple Self Referencing One To Many Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have a database table like this:
[image]

Now, I want to make self referencing one-to-many between states, cities and villages.

Each state has many cities and each city has many villages.

Note that city has two relations:

- **many cities -> one state**
- **one city -> many villages**

How should I do that using Doctrine yml configs, entity annotations and forms?

Comment: Your model is wrong, consider doing 3 entities: State, City and Village. Then, you will be able to easily linked them with ManyToOne relations.

Comment: +1 @GreenLeaf  you are correct , if I may add suggestion : creating a tree model , I guess it would be understood easily , easily compared to real life State -> City -> Village https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @GreenLeaf, that your model is wrong. It is impossible to distinguish how two records of your model are related keeping it common sense.

First, you might want to read about database normalization:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Second, if you really insist on keeping your data intact, you could try to make ManyToMany reations so doctrine would create 3 additional tables, and there you could distinguish the type of relation by definig proper field names. Reading here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html lets call your table "Districts" you could try:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Districts")
 * @JoinTable(name="Cities",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */


/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Districts")
 * @JoinTable(name="Villages",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="village_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

This might work for you

Comment: I edited my model and created 3 entities with one-to-many relationships, but the problem is still what it was !